# Python - Pop element from for loop and append to end, modifying list while looping

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

For every element in a for loop, I want to check if the element satisfies some condition. If yes, I want to do something to it; if no, I want to add it to the end of the list and do it later.

I'm aware that modifying loops while looping is bad, but I want to do it anyway, and want to know how to do it correctly.

```
for i in list:
    if something(i):
        do(i)
    else:
        #append to end of list, do later
        list.remove(i)
        list.append(i)
```

This piece of code mostly works, but causes me to skip the element after the removed i while iterating. How do I work around that?

Comment: post your `list` and `edges`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think `list` and `edges` are the same list.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, messed up the generic-ification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no correct way to modify a list while looping over a list. In particular, removing objects from a list will cause issues (see [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)).

I would consider making additional lists, one for your results, one temp list for the elements you have left to process. Note that in my example, tmp1 is your input list.

```
tmp1 = [values to process]
tmp2 = []
results = []
while(tmp1)
    for i in tmp1:
        if something(i):
            results.append(i)
            do(i)
        else:
            tmp2.append(i)
    tmp1 = tmp2
    tmp2 = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized just after asking that I don't even need to remove if I'm only ever going to iterate through the list once - if I just append, I'll be able to operate on the element once everything else is finished.

In other words, this works:

```
for i in list:
    if something(i):
        do(i)
    else:
        #append to end of list, do later
        list.append(i)
```

Comment: And you don't care that the items you previously skipped stay in the list?

Comment: Memory will blow up, why not?